# Regex to match {12} digit number & other pattern, multiline, when any characters can be between them

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex, but I am not sure at this point, if it is possible:

As my example: https://regex101.com/r/JRBYyw/6

Requirements:

- I need regex to match 12 numbers
- after or before 12 numbers there can be ANY characters in multiple - different amount of lines
- I want to match pattern `[A-Z]{4}\s?\d{7}` which can be after 12 digit number random-amount of times (between them again, random other characters in multiple lines)
- I want to match `[A-Z]{4}\s?\d{7}` so many times, until there is another 12 digit number somewhere in the text before it - not only directly before it, but between other text again.
- If it helps we can assume that 12 digit number and A-Z pattern will be on a new line, at the start of it.

Comment: Can you give some example input and output strings?

Comment: Do you need to store all your `\d{12}`s and all your `A-Z]{4}\s?\d{7}`s for further processing?

Comment: What's wrong with `^(?:\d{12}|[A-Z]{4}\s?\d{7})$`? See https://regex101.com/r/IltWda/1

Comment: Or  do you need `^(3\d{11})\R+([\s\S]*?)(?=\R3\d{11}|\z)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/JRBYyw/8))?

Comment: E.i. input: 
315445640491
neco1
neco2
neco3
ABCD
8604301
neco1
neco2
neco3
ABBB
8604302
ABBB
8604303
315445640492
ABBB
8604304
neco1
neco2
neco3

Output: 
315445640491
ABCD
8604301
ABBB
8604302
ABBB
8604303
315445640492
ABBB
8604304

- I need to store **{12}digit number** and all **ABCD{7}number** under it. 
**315445640491 - ABCD8604301,ABBB8604302, ABBB8604303
315445640492 - ABBB8604304  .. etc**

 `^(?:\d{12}|[A-Z]{4}\s?\d{7})$` This is workaround I will use, maybe a little different, like `(\d{12})|([a-zA-Z]{4}(\s)?\d{7})` so I catch all ABCD patterns

Comment: `^(3\d{11})\R+([\s\S]*?)(?=\R3\d{11}|\z)` This is also something I would use as workaround, to parse the text and search for `[A-Z]{4}\n\d{7}` in those chunks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a two-pass approach: 1) extract all blocks of texts that start with 12-digit numbers and span up to the next 12-digit number or end of text, and 2) then extract the letter-digit patterns from each block.

Here is the first regex:

```
^(3\d{11})\R+([\s\S]*?)(?=\R3\d{11}|\z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JRBYyw/8). The 12-digit numbers are in Group 1 here. Then, take Group 2 as input for

```
\d{12}|[a-zA-Z]{4}\s?\d{7}
```

that matches either 12 digits, or four letters, an optional whitespace and then seven digits.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JRBYyw/9)